# Usage of accessor methods

Tags: java, getter-setter

**This is my class containing setters and getters**

```
package Pack;

public class Details {

String FirstName,LastName,City,Country;

    public Details(String firstName, String lastName, String city,
            String country) {
        super();
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        City = city;
        Country = country;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return FirstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        FirstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return LastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return City;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        City = city;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return Country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        Country = country;
    }
}
```

===========================================================================

This is my main()

```
package Pack;

public class MainClass {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Details d = new Details("Hari","L","Bangalore","India");

    }

}
```

==========================================================================

I know my main() is incomplete. What should i write to display the contents of "d"?

Comment: Change `String FirstName,LastName,City,Country;` to `private String firstName, lastName, city, country;`. By convention Java variables are camelCase and class names are PascalCase. Use `this.` to distinguish between class-scope variables and method parameters or method variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways.

One, just print each property of your details object :

`System.out.println("FirstName :"+d.getFirstName());` etc..

Or, a better option would be to override `toString()` method in your class

```
public void toString() {
        return this.getFirstName()+ " " + this.getLastName()+" "+.... ;
}
```

and then just print your class `System.out.println(d);`

Comment: @Everyone: Take note how Nishan is using the accessor methods within `toString()`, rather than directly using the instance variables themselves. This opens numerous possibilities.

Comment: After getting tired of typing in toString methods, take a look at one of the libraries that help with this like: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ToStringBuilder.html

Answer (score 2):

Override toString() method in Details as follow and then just call to print what you want:

```
public String toString(){
   return this.firstName+" "+this.lastName+" "+this.city+" "+this.country;
}
```

in main just call it as `System.out.println(d);`

Comment: Do i need to "override" or "generate" tostring()?

Comment: @hari: just copy/paste method from my answer to your code. It will auto override. And if you wish you can add `@Override` annotation on the top of method.

Comment: as this is supposed to be a function for the Details class, do not call on the instance of d. Instead, either use the field variables FirstName, LastName, etc. or call the methods getFirstName() etc.

return getFirstName()+" "+LastName+...

Comment: If you successfully overridden `toString()` method, you can do `System.out.println(d);` (see how I've omitted the `toString()`).

Answer (score 2):

you need a toString() method in Details class:

```
public String toString(){
   return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + ", " + this.city + " " + this.country;
}
```

and

```
System.out.println(d.toString());
```

in main

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
System.out.printf("%s %s (%s, %s)\n", d.getFirstName(), d.getLastName(), d.getCity(), d.getCountry());
```

I would make your fields (FirstName, LastName, City, and Country) private, otherwise there's not much point in using getters and setters.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add methods (or something similar with more properties):

```
public String asFirstnameLastname()
{
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
}

public String asLastNameFirstname()
{
   return lastName + " " + firstName;
}
```

toString() is also a good choice.

Comment: Adding convenience getter-as methods does not display the class contents.